# Using resolve to show loading animation in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying (for the first time) to show a loading animation while my page loads. For now, my loading animation is just a black box in my html

```
<div id="loading" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: black;"></div>
```

My module config looks like this

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("4PCApp")

    .config(function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('list', {
                url: '/list',
                controller: 'ListCtrl as vm',
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/list/list.html',
                resolve: {
                  app: function ($q) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $('#loading').show();
                    defer.resolve();
                    return defer.promise.then(function(){
                      $('#loading').hide();
                    })
                  }
                },
                data: {pageTitle: 'List'}
            })
    })

    .controller('ListCtrl',['$scope', '$state', '$log', 'ServerRequest', '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', 'uiGridConstants', '$rootScope', '$interval', function ($scope, $state, $log, ServerRequest, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, uiGridConstants, $rootScope, $interval) {
```

I am clearly not understanding something with the resolve pattern, as the black box shows, but does not disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are mixing some concepts here... ui-router's 'resolve' function is not related to a Promise's resolve callback... it could be easier to use an existing component though - https://github.com/entrecode/angular-state-loader

Comment: What's the actual thing you're loading - a $http call or something?

Comment: Thanks. im going to try angular state loader, and learn more about resolve.

Comment: There is an ajax call that gets about 10,000 objects from a backend.. something like this:

         `          ServerRequest.getAllPatients({
          }).then(function(resp){
            console.log('resp', resp);
            $scope.myTestData = resp
          }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
          });`

Comment: The router does not load the view controller until **after** the resolution of the promises returned from the resolve function. If the div named #loading is inside the view template, it wont event exist when the `.hide` method executes. Thus, of course, it won't go away.